# MySQL - Query to split an integer bitwise field into a boolean column for each bit

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Given the following example data:

```
mysql> select * from test2;
+-------+--------+
| name  | status |
+-------+--------+
| bob   |      0 |
| jim   |      2 |
| karen |      5 |
| jane  |      1 |
| roy   |      7 |
+-------+--------+
```

I want to come up with a query which will split out the value of the status column into a pseudo-boolean value column for each individual bit of the integer.

What I do now is to have the application generate a query that uses a case statement and bitwise and operator for each column to get the result, like so:

```
mysql> select 
    ->     name, 
    ->     (case when (status & 1) then 'yes' else 'no' end) as bit1, 
    ->     (case when (status & 2) then 'yes' else 'no' end) as bit2, 
    ->     (case when (status & 4) then 'yes' else 'no' end) as bit4, 
    ->     (case when (status & 8) then 'yes' else 'no' end) as bit8 
    -> from test2;
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| name  | bit1 | bit2 | bit4 | bit8 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| bob   | no   | no   | no   | no   |
| jim   | no   | yes  | no   | no   |
| karen | yes  | no   | yes  | no   |
| jane  | yes  | no   | no   | no   |
| roy   | yes  | yes  | yes  | no   |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now this works, and does so efficiently since there are no sub queries or joins, but it's not very elegant.

I would like a more elegant solution to do this dynamically without having to create a case statement and test for every bit.

This is example data with only a few bits, but in the implementation proper, there will be tens of thousands of rows, and many more bits that can be set.

**Bonus:**

Base the generation of the columns (column name and test) off of a table containing the definition of each bit like the following:

```
mysql> select * from bit_spec;
+-----+------+
| bit | desc |
+-----+------+
|   1 | bit1 |
|   2 | bit2 |
|   4 | bit3 |
|   8 | bit4 |
+-----+------+
```

Currently, the application handles this, and it's not a hard requirement that this processing be done by the MySQL server instead, but it would be advantageous if it was.

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f6d0/1) containing the example data, example bit definition table, and my current solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by retrieving each user/bit/value combination into rows and then pivoting those rows into columns.

```
select 
  name, 
  `desc`,
  ((status & bit) > 0) value
from test2, bit_spec
```

The query above produces results in the following format

```
name  |  desc  |  value
bob   |  bit1  |  0
bob   |  bit2  |  0
```

From here we can pivot the results into the desired format where each `desc`/`value` pair is converted into a column named `desc` with value `value`.

Using the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/12005676/3574819

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when `desc` = ''',
      `desc`,
      ''' then value end) AS ',
      replace(`desc`, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from bit_spec;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT t1.name, ', @sql, ' from
(select 
  name, 
  `desc`,
  ((status & bit) > 0) value
from test2, bit_spec) t1
group by t1.name
order by t1.name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f6d0/22

```
NAME        BIT1    BIT2    BIT3    BIT4
bob         0       0       0       0
jane        1       0       0       0
jim         0       1       0       0
karen       1       0       1       0
roy         1       1       1       0
```

**Sidenote**

If you need to search by permission (i.e. show all users that have bit1 & bit2 but not bit3) then I don't recommend storing your permissions as bits in a single integer because the db can't index the results. In that case an indexed join table consisting of columns (user_id, permission_id) would yield faster results.

Comment: It will mostly be used for reporting purposes, there will be a few tests made against it, but there are some interesting ways to work around the efficiency issues with bitwise fields in MySQL[1], so I'm not entirely worried about it. Your answer looks good, and I'll most likely accept it after doing some tests.

[1] http://explainextended.com/2009/10/01/bitwise-operations-and-indexes/